# C++ idioms when declaring template class members and constructors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, syntax

Although both of the following compile (with Visual Studio 2013), is one of them more "correct" with respect to C++ idioms?  I speak particularly with respect to explicit template parameters when calling base class constructors and declaring members.  Does The Standard have a view on this?  Is there a good practical reason to prefer one over the other?

```
template<class T>
class Bar1 : public Base<T>
{
public:

    Bar1() : Base() {}
    Bar1(T value) : Base(value) {}
    Bar1(Bar1 const & other) : Base(other.value) {} 

    void Foo(Bar1 const & other)
    {
        // Some foo related activity.
    }
};

template<class T>
class Bar2 : public Base<T>
{
public:

    Bar2() : Base<T>() {}
    Bar2(T value) : Base<T>(value) {}
    Bar2(Bar2<T> const & other) : Base<T>(other.value) {}

    void Foo(Bar2<T> const & other)
    {
        // Some foo related activity.
    }
};
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, only `Bar2` is syntactically correct. What compiler did you use and did you actually call all the constructors of `Bar1`?

Comment: The first form shouldn't work, because it trys to refer to the injected-class-name (which acts like a public member) of a dependent base class. You must be using MSVC, which doesn't correctly implement the name lookup rule.

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2013.  I made a simple repo and it compiles and everything is as expected (working correctly).  Well that's interesting cpplearner.  The bad habits we pick up because of things like this.

Comment: Then it's one of the cases, where MSVC++ is able to parse non standard conformant template code. `Bar2` is the better (only) way to go.

Comment: @cpplearner You should turn this into an answer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2974780/509868

Comment: It would seem that `Base<T>` has to spelled out, but `Bar2` can be used instead of `Bar2<T>` without being qualified with `<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question relies on something called *injected-class-name*. From [class]

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen. The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.
>   For purposes of access checking, the *injected-class-name* is treated as if it were a public member name.

And from [temp.local]:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9). The *injected-class-name* can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a *template-argument-list*,
>   as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent
>   to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.

That is, within the definitions `Bar1<T>` or `Bar2<T>`, you can use `Bar1` or `Bar2` to refer to the full class type. That is, these declarations are equivalent:

```
void Foo(Bar2<T> const & other);
void Foo(Bar2 const & other);
```

However, the rules for lookup apply as normal. While there *is* an injected-class-name for `Base`, that is a dependent name and so cannot be found via normal unqualified lookup. From [temp.dep]:

> In the definition of a class or class template, the scope of a dependent base class (14.6.2.1) is not examined
>   during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

which makes this:

```
Bar1() : Base() {}
```

ill-formed. `Base` is unqualified lookup, and there is no such name `Base`. There is a `Base<T>::Base` (the injected-class-name there), but that scope is unexamined. You would have to either do qualified lookup:

```
Bar1() : Bar1<T>::Base() {}
Bar1() : Bar1::Base() { }
```

or not rely on the injected-class-name of `Base`:

```
Bar1() : Base<T>() { }
```

VS is wrong in accepting `Bar1`. `Bar2` is perfectly OK, if more verbose than strictly possible. Nothing wrong with that.

Worth noting also that if the base weren't dependent, you could still use its injected-class-name even if it were a template:

```
template <class T> struct Base { };

struct Derived : Base<int> {
    Derived() : Base() { } // OK, lookup finds Base<int>::Base
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The first form is incorrect and should not compile.  To see why, consider what would happen if you multiply inherited from `Base<Foo>` and `Base<Bar>` (or `Base<T>` and `Base<Base<T>>` or whatever).  How could it resolve the ambiguity?

The idea that the first form would work may be derived from mistaken application of the rule that, within a class template definition, you don't need to provide the template param(s) when mentioning the class name.  This doesn't apply to a templated base class, though.